# Rotating a letter in a word 180 degrees in html/css?

Tags: html, css

How can I rotate a letter in a word so it's back to front. For example in the word Butter , I want to flip the first 't' so it faces the other way? So they are next to each other and their backs facing eachother.How can I do this in html/css ? I hope this question makes sense. I have searched the net but only find  reversing whole words or sentences and I only want one letter in a word.

Comment: Do you want to rotate it 180 degrees (which means the letter will be upside down) or do you want a mirror image (which means the letter will be flipped along the vertical axis)? From your explanation you actually want the latter (mirror image).

Comment: Not upside down ,the other way around/back to front.

Answer (score 1):

To rotate a single letter in a word you can use CSS to apply a transformation to that specific letter:

```css
.word {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rotated-letter {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="word">
    Bu<span class="rotated-letter">t</span>ter
</div>
```

Comment: is it maybe possible that you could show me how to do it with the word <h1>Butter</h1> and I want the middle 't' to flip?

Comment: in the example I did it with the word butter, if you need to add H1 as well, you just have to insert it first:
<h1>Bu<span class="rotated-letter">t</span>ter</h1>

Comment: Thanks a lot but then it looks like this Bu.      (flipped't').       ter .So spaces in between.

Comment: But *******(flipped 't')*******ter

Comment: This problem with h1 does not happen for me. @Knersuz please show the code that is giving this spaces problem. It may be there is other CSS involved (the browser devtools inspect facility will show exactly what CSS is being applied).

Comment: Thanks a lot got it fixed now,just have to add padding:0 margin: 0 to each span

Comment: Much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Put the one letter you want to flip in a separate span. Then style it with `transform: scaleX(-1)`.

Comment: you mean like this? <span>But</span><span style: transform: scaleX(-1)>t</span><span>er</span>.              sorry beginner here

Comment: Thanks it works but then there are spaces in between the parts.

Comment: Then leave out the spaces from between the `>`s and `<`s.

Answer (score -1):

HTML: Create an HTML element for the letter you want to rotate. For example:

html

A
CSS: Define a CSS class that applies the rotation:

css
.rotate {display: inline-block; /* Ensures inline behavior */
transform: rotate(180deg); /* Rotate by 180 degrees */}
Apply the Class: Add the "rotate" class to the letter or element you want to rotate.

This code will rotate the letter (or element) with the class "rotate" by 180 degrees. Adjust the class and styling as needed for your specific use case.

Comment: This is rotating around the wrong axis.